Graph Theory and Unsolvable Equations
I was reading Trudeau’s Introduction to Graph Theory, and I was thinking about the connection between non-planar graphs and unsolvable polynomial equations, such as the quintic. It’s a really interesting coincidence that both K_5 and the quintic equation are unsolvable in their respective senses. Does this connection continue with other graphs? For example, the Utility Graph K_{3,3} is nonplanar; does this imply that the bivariate cubic equation, Ay^3+By^2+Cy+Dx^3+Ex^2+Fx+G=0, has no algebraic solution?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

What does it mean for a graph to be (un)solvable? There is more than one way in which this could be interpreted. For example, one can ask if given fixed edge-lengths, the $(x,y)$-coordinates of vertices can be solved for with radicals, and $K_5$ can be solved in such a way but $K_{3,3}$ can't.

Solvability in this case would mean the generation of a planar graph. It is impossible for UG and K_5, and for all graphs containing a subgraph this is a subdivision of K_5 or UG. How does this connect to the solvability of certain degrees and orders of multivariate polynomial equations?
